# Running a .exe inside WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a bootstrapping application in WSL2 (a bash script) that will go and download Windows binaries (`.exe`s), and then I would like to run them. I know there are ways to run them WSL2, I just can't figure it out.

I verified that I can use Powershell on the host, navigate into my WSL2 directories, and run `./Program.exe` and have it run within powershell.

I can also use WSL2, and run `powershell.exe` via: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe`, which opens a Powershell instance within WSL2. However, when I try and run `./Program.exe` through this Powershell instance, I get the following error:

```
Program 'Program.exe' failed to run: Incorrect functionAt line:1 char:1
+ ./Program.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./Program.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I have also tried doing this in other variations, such as:

- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe Invoke-Expression -Command "$(wslpath -w ./Program.exe)"`
- `"$(wslpath -m ./Program.exe)" | /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command Invoke-Expression`
- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command Start-Process Program.exe`
- `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command Start-Process ./Program.exe -Verb runas`
- etc. etc.

Again, I verified that these command do work in the host Powershell; it's just when I try to run them within WSL2 that it fails.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Information requested by @Luuk:

- The `Program.exe` application is pulled from an Azure DevOps pipelines, using the Azure CLI.
- The application is a C# application that runs on Windows and opens a SignalR connection to a SignalR hub, and waits and responds to SignalR messages. It requires no user input, and runs until the process is stopped manually.

As I said, I verified that the artifacts downloaded from the pipeline can manually be run by going into the WSL2 folder through File Explorer, double-clicking the `.exe`, and confirming a window comes up and starts spitting out logs.

However, running through WSL2, it does not start.

Comment: Can you share the output of `file Program.exe` ?  (Or explain, in details, where Program.exe is coming from)

Comment: @Luuk Updated OP.

Comment: Try: `cmd.exe /c Program.exe`, or share the source of this C# application so your problem is reproduceable (see: [mre])